# Using MS Excel Keyboard shortcuts on Ubuntu

Tags: wine, shortcut-keys, microsoft-office

I recently switched again from Windows to Ubuntu 13.04. I use MS Excel a lot, and don't want to exchange it from Libre Office. For me it runs fine with Wine. However the reason I switch back to Windows every time I use Excel is that Ubuntu doesn't seem to support the Keyboard Shortcuts (Alt+ ...). Instead it opens the Unity launcher. Did anyone ever got Keyboard shortcuts working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could avoid Unity and use Xubuntu or Lubuntu instead.

Answer (score 0):

The Trick is to Keep Alt Pressed when using the commands...
Have been working on Ubuntu for 2 years..Except for selection on Filters using Space bar..no issues.

PS : Macros do not work in Wine..

Answer (score 0):

Goto System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcut -> Launchers -> 
Click Key to show HUD and press backspace to disable it.

This will disable HUD display on Unity. 
Now you can use Alt Key for excel.